# How to extend the "s" string interpolator

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to create a new string interpolator macro, lets call it 'X', that functions like "s" when it comes to interpolating new values in.  The string I pass into my interpolator is first passed through "s" and then the resultant string is post-processed by 'X'.  Optimally I'd like the string to be resolved before it even hits the macro.  Is that possible at compile time?  I don't want the macro to know about any referenced variables.

Thanks!

```
implicit class XInterp (val sc : StringContext) {
   def X(args: Any*): String = macro XMacro
}

def XMacro(c: Context)(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[String] = {
   // args(0).tree == "Foo has a value of 5 and this is awesome!"?
}

val foo = 5
val bar = "this is awesome!"
val result = X"Foo has a value of $foo and $bar"
println(result)

"Foo has a value of 5 and this is awesome!"
```

Comment: I'm currently thinking I'll have to use 'enclosingImpl', as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857130/how-to-print-variable-name-and-value-using-a-scala-macro

Comment: It is not possible at compile time, the "s" function will be translated to StringContext("str", "").s(args) by the compiler.
Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do in the "X" function?